# Return Data From Other Component [React Native/React]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

hope you guys have a great great day! :)

I want to ask something, i need to return some list data from API,

I have 3 files, one called `getUser.js` and the othe is `User.js` and `OtherUser.js`, i already fetch the data from API in `getUser.js`, and i need to access the data from `getUser.js` to populate `User.js` and `OtherUser.js`

**The Problem is**, i can't return the data in `getUser.js`

here's my code in `getUser.js`

```js
import React from "react";

export const getUser = async () => {
  await fetch("https://myapi.com")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
};
```

and when i `console.log` inside `User.js` and `OtherUser.js`, i got this

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

[image: the log]

and here's my code in `User.js` and `OtherUser.js` looks like:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { getUser } from './someplace/getUser'

export default function User() {
  useEffect(()=>{getDataFromUser()},[])

  const getDataFromUser = async() => {
   console.log(getUser())
  }
}
```

Did you guys know why? please help :)

Comment: You have to `await getUser()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `then` chains, when using async-await. Refactor your `getUser` funciton to

```
export const getUser = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://myapi.com");
  const json = await response.json();
  return json;
};
```

Then in your `User` component

```
console.log(await getUser())
```

Comment: Thanksss brotherr!!

Comment: above is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are logging a Promise, that's why you're seeing this in your console.

When inside async function, if you want to get the result of the function, you should not use "then".

So you could do something like this:

```
const getUser = async () => {
  let response = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/get");
  return await response.json();
};
```

**But, notice that if fetch fails, it may throw an exception. So I recommend using a try/catch block**

Also notice that in this case, when you call getUser(), you will have to use "await" before calling the function to get the json response. For example:

```
let user = await getUser();
```

In case you want to run a async function inside the useEffect hook, try doing something like this:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  onOpen = async () => {            
    console.log(await getUser());
  }
  onOpen();
},[]);
```